# NightwatchJS+Cucumber cannot locate via xPath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I am using Nightwatch-cucumber and page objects and I am struggling to get the locators to find my element via Xpath.

element looks like this:

```
<div class="portal-layout-section" style="width: 1215px; height: 730px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="item bordered portal-hoverable" style="width: 243px; height: 365px; background-image: url(http://path/to/img/Ironman.jpeg;);"></div>
<div class="item bordered portal-hoverable" style="width: 243px; height: 365px; background-image: url(http://path/to/img/FriendsWithBenefits.jpeg);"></div>
<div class="item bordered portal-hoverable" style="width: 243px; height: 365px; background-image: url(http://path/to/img/Inception.jpeg);"></div></div>
</div>
```

My step contains this code:

```
var anonbrowse = this.page.anonbrowse();
 anonbrowse  
    .waitForElementVisible('@cover_images_ironman',5000)
    .click('@cover_images_ironman')
```

And the Pageobject looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
elements: {
     cover_images_ironman: {
       selector : '//div[contains(@style,"http://path/to/img/Ironman.jpeg")]',
       locateStrategy: "xpath"          

    },
 }
}
```

I keep getting a timeout error not matter how long I leave the wait:

```
Timed out while waiting for element <//div[contains(@style,"http://path/to/img//Ironman.jpeg")]> to be present for 5000 milliseconds. - Expected "visible" but got: "not found"
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\nightwatxh\features\step_definitions\anonbrowse_steps.js:21:3)
    at next (native)
    at next (native)
```

Anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does simplifying it to `//div[contains(@style,"Ironman.jpeg")]` make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: thanks, just tried that and still no luck.  I've tried the xpath I am using in a chrome plugin 'xpath helper' and it is highlighting the right element, so I know that xpath is right.

Answer (score 0):

try locator like this:

```
selector: '//div[contains(@style, "background-image: url(http://path/to/img//Ironman.jpeg))"]'
```

i could make misatke somewhere with "" or ''

Comment: Thanks, yes have tried that but no luck, nightwatchjs is able to identify the element as I have done an assertion, but it just cannot click it.  I am not sure if its something to do with this Div being a React component.

Comment: try css selector like this `.item.bordered.portal-hoverable:nth-child(1)`, it should work and we are going to know if there is a problem with an element or just with nightwatch

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still no luck.  This assert works: 
      `.expect.element('@cover_images_ironman').to.have.css('background-image').which.contains('url("http://Ironman.jpeg")');` But when i click, its still not working:   `.click('@cover_images_ironman')`